# No se muestra el google maps en mi dispositvo real

Tags: android, google-maps

Cuando genero el APK en mi celular no muestra google map.

**Mi clase:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng jockey = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(jockey).title("Signey"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(jockey));
    }
}
```

**Mi xml:**

```
<fragment

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context="com.example.mauri.googlemapsandroid2.MapsActivity">


</fragment>
```

**mi manifest:**
En el manifest puse todos los permisos correspondientes y llame la Api key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mauri.googlemapsandroid2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Ya cree mis credenciales en el Google maps, genere el `API_KEY`, y el `SHA1` pero igual no sale en mi dispositivo real. Solo sale en la parte inferior izquierdo la palabra Google.

Estoy intentando intentando y nada. Alguien que me de una ayuda por favor

Comment: Y ya obtuviste tu API Key a partir del SHA-1 del Keystore?

Comment: mm , como sería eso amigo ?

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no configuraste el xml; `google_maps_api.xml` 
 se encuenta en ; *Vaules/google_maps_api.xml*

Este archivo se encuentra un vinculo, este te llevara a unos pasos donde generaste tus Key por medio de **Google API Console**. Aquella clave o key debes pegarla en el archivo `xml` ya mencionado en el principio.

Quedaria asi

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        //Tu clave va en este lugar ...
    </string>
```

Y si ya no se resuelve tu problema, creo que deberías revisar tu conexión, nunca esta demás.

Comment: esta con el nombre google_maps_key en mi manifest:

Comment: en tu carpeta value no tienes el xml?

Comment: si si esta con el nombre de: google_maps_api.xml (debug)

Comment: En aquel XML existe una URL donde debes obtender tu clave y esa clave colocarla donde te dije ...

Comment: claro mi API_KEY que me da google, esta en aquel xml pues.

Comment: podrias añadir tu xml a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: mi xml llamado: google_maps_api

<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIza...........WRes --- EL api que google me da----</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el `API_KEY` en el `manifest` e intenta compilar, por lo general si se encuentra en el archivo `google_maps_api.xml`.

No se carga al compilar el `apk`, otra punto que debes tener en cuenta es que la consola de `Google API`, tiene en cuenta el `SHA1` generado por el android estudio donde estas realizando tu proyecto, por experiencia, si cambias de pc, debes generar un nuevo `activity maps` y generar tu api key nuevamente, y así no tendrás problemas.